# how to find int value within span class Selenium C#

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, webdriver, c#

The `int` value inside the bold span class is a count of results, which will vary. I want to find it so I can validate it against a database `get`.

```
<span class="baseline float-left blocking-rule-table__extra-header-text">

<span class="bold">20</span> Results</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

I know selenium with java.
I don't know the selenium in c#, but still crux would still be the same. You should use `FindElement` by xpath then use the `Text` property to get the value. That would be in String. Use `TryParse` to convert to integer value if it is an integer.

```
String t=ext.FindElement(By.XPath("'.//*[@id='primary']/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/span")).Text;
int value = 0;
int.TryParse(t, out value);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the int appears every time after the word "Result" ,then simply split the text at "String t" by the letter "R".
Pass the result in to an array.
Select the [0]th element from the array.
Bingoo.